# Lost reputation - not sure why

Tags: support, reputation

My reputation dropped -15.  I can't see any downvotes in my history.  Any ideas why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably someone unaccepted one of your answers. That'd account for lost 15 rep, but wouldn't show up on the history.